# Swift - return type that uses a protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement [DeepLinkSDK](http://www.usebutton.com/sdk/deep-links/integration-guide) in a Swift project but I'm having problems converting this to swift:

```
@implementation ProductRouteHandler

- (UIViewController <DPLTargetViewController> *)targetViewController {
  return [[ProductDetailViewController alloc] init];
}

@end
```

Can anyone give me a help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that you can specify a return type that means “some subclass of `A` that conforms to `T`”, but what you can do is just set the return type to `ProductDetailViewController`, as Swift allows [covariant return types for methods overridden in subclasses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Covariant_method_return_type) (like Java, C++ or Scala).

```
override func targetViewController() -> ProductDetailViewController  {
    return ProductDetailViewController()
}
```